# Workflow no-code authoring

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-activity

I want to use the no-code authoring in the workflow. So no code behind. Let's say I have 2 custom activities with dependency properties.

How can I bind a property from activity1 to activity2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use Activity binding in a no code behind scenario.

In the designer select activity2 and in the property grid uses the ... button on the target property.  This opens the "Bind 'Property' to an activity's property" dialog.  Navigate to Activity1 and select the source property from it.

Or if you want to be hardcode you can tweak up the XOML:-

```
<ns0:Activity2 SomeProperty="{ActivityBind Activity1, Path=SomeOtherProperty}" ..>
```